# Access SQL - Is it possible to group by switch values?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

Using Access 2010, I am trying to group by switch values and currently having trouble working out the code. Basically, within the treatment field in my DB, I have values such as D1, D2, D3, E1, E2, E3. The first letter denotes a particular treatment type e.g. D = Treatment1, E = Treatment2. I am looking to group the data by 'Treatment1' and 'Treatment2' for example.

```
SELECT switch(LEFT(t1.[treatment],1)='D',"Treatment1",LEFT(t1.[treatment],1)='E',"Treatment2"), count(t1.[UniqueID]) AS Total_Population, count(t2.[date]) AS DateSent, format(count(t2.[date]) / count(t1.[UniqueID]),"0.00%") AS Percentage_Sent, COUNT(IIF(t1.[requirements]='1',1,)) AS requirements_population
FROM Main_table AS t1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT t2.[ID], t2.[date] FROM Main_table AS t2 WHERE t2.date Not Like ('NA'))  AS t2 ON t1.[ID] = t2.[ID]
GROUP BY  [treatment]
```

Expected output is for example, Treatment1 - x amount, Treatment2 - y amount. However at present I get multiple rows of both Treatment1 & Treatment2 as the data behind those expressions is not unique (i.e. D1, D2, D3, E1, E2, E3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to:

```
GROUP BY LEFT(t1.[treatment], 1)
```

so you group by the 1st letter of `t1.[treatment]` and not `t1.[treatment]`